# How to extract data and combine data from JSON

Tags: oracle-adf

I retrieve data from source via a REST interface and copy them to CRM via a "Copy data" action.
Let's just call them "devices" and "locations". Copy and linking works fine, so the basic data are available.

For some unknown reason, the serial number of the device is not part of the data for devices. Instead we have an ID and "name". Currently serial numbers are being entered manually in CRM, but we would really like to use ADF to copy them.

I notied that the "name" of the device as well as serial numbers are shown in the location data.

I have shortened the output a lot and made a simple example to show the structure:
So I need to take each value in @data.devices and pair it with the value @data.devicelist.
In the example below, "device1.name" should be paired with "serial" for id=1 in the devicelist and so on.

Finally I need to update the serial number in CRM in the "devices" entity using the device "name" as key.

```json
 
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "locationid": 1,
        "devices": [
          **"device1.name",**
          "device2.name"
        ],
        "devicelist": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            **"Serial": "XXXXXXXX",**
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "Serial": "YYYYYYYY",
          }
        `],
        {....}
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried to see if I could make it using data flow, but I have no idea how to par the device "name" and serial number and make it into a dataset, that can be used to update the data in CRM.